# 飲食店が入る雑居ビル vs 飲食店が入った雑居ビル

Tags: grammar, tense, relative-clauses

A news program announced:

> 〇〇店が入る雑居ビルが全焼した。

I was expecting

> 〇〇店が入った雑居ビルが全焼した。

as in 「水が入ったグラス」. The former seems like it's saying that the shop was going to be set up in the building sometime in the future, but it was clear from context that the building already contained the shop. What is the difference?

Comment: Might as well handle the 〇〇店が入**っている**雑居ビル case too here.

Comment: 〇〇店が入っていた雑居ビル means that  the building don't contain the shop now.

Comment: I find the stative use of 入る completely natural in cases where it expresses elements or subsets of a set, e.g. google "カテゴリに入る", but in the more concrete "be inside" meaning here I find it a bit strange, so I'll wait for others to comment/reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> 〇〇店が入る雑居ビル

It can be interpreted 2 ways.

1. 〇〇店 plan to set up a store in the building (future)
2. 〇〇店 already have a store in the building (present)

The sentence itself is ambiguous. It can be mean the future or present. But you can distinguish one from another according to the context in most cases, as you did in the news program.

By the way, this is not a special case of verb 入る, but any verb works like this.

For example

> 私の働く会社

It can mean "The company I works for" or "The company I will work for".

When you say

> 〇〇店が入った雑居ビル

It is clear the sentence only talking about the present, not the future.

In conclusion when you say 〇〇店が入る the sentence itself is ambiguous (but you usually can distinguish according to the context), 〇〇店が入った is not ambiguous it only talking about the present. In other words, there is no practical difference in cases the context is clear.

News program prefer shorter sentences when there is no chance to misunderstand. I think that's why the news program use 入る rather than 入った.